# Eigen operations with unsigned type

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm using Eigen to compute the difference between two matrices of type `unsigned char`.

```
 Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, 4, 1> C0;
 Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, 4, 1> C1;
 C0 << 255, 0, 127, 1;
 C1 << 0, 255, 128, 255;
 std::cout << (C0 - C1).cast<int>() << "\n";
```

The results are `255 1 255 2`. I'd like the operation to saturate in case of underflow (or overflow if it was an addition), resulting in `255 0 0 0`. Is that possible with Eigen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing readily available inside Eigen for this. You could [provide a custom type](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html) which overloads `operator+`, `operator-`, etc. like you intend.

Of course, ideally this should use saturating SIMD instructions (e.g., `_mm_subs_epi8` if you have SSE2) internally, but that is not very easy to integrate into Eigen -- especially if your matrix sizes are not multiples of 16 bytes.